# Customer notifications

Tags: customer, shipping

We are seeing an increase in customers saying they have not received notifications of the order places or the shipment & tracking has been received even though we do all the steps.

Is there a way to or update that would provide proof the customer received any email we sent?

Answer (score 0):

customer forget password request sent if email sent that means email functionality working.